# Opencart Login Categories

Tags: php, authentication, opencart

I need to create a log-in for all categories apart from one with its own ID, say '192'

In controller/category.php I added the below...

```
if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
    $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL');
    $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
}
```

But this obviously adds a login for all categories.

What would be the best way to add to the code above to make category '192' not have to login to view?

Answer (score 0):

Open `catalog/controller/product/category.php` and remove the code you have above from wherever it is. Then find

```
if ($category_info) {
```

After that, put

```
if (!$this->customer->isLogged() && $category_id != 192) {
    $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL');
    $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will give it a try and let you know!